# How to change function parameter and run it with near cli?

Tags: nearprotocol

Currently, I learn near with the project "helloworld-demo-assembly". I deploy and use contract successfully but when I add a new parameter to the function `helloWorld` and run it with near cli, it does not change.
[image: Add new parameter to function helloWorld]
[image: Run near view command with contract]

Comment: did you compiled and re deployed the code before calling it?

Comment: Yes, i compiled and re deployed the code, i follow exactly instruction in readme.md.

Comment: Can you provide us with the link to the repository?

Comment: I add a new answer below, thanks. For someone who interesting in, i provide the repo link here: [link](https://github.com/NEAR-Edu/hello-world-demo-assemblyscript.git)

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem. Whenever i change function, i need to call deploy.script again and it will apply the change.

Answer (score -1):

When you send a parameter to function, this means it will change state. That's why you have to use `call` instead of `view`.

Use `near call $CONTRACT helloWorld '{"name": "hehe"}'`

Comment: Adding a parameter to a function does not mean you are changing the state. State changes when you modify the actual state in the contract.